# C#, getting access to Documents and Settings in Vista?

Tags: c#

I am writing an app for vista that would need to access such folders as MyDocuments, MyPictures, Destop, etc... yet to get into them I first need to get into "Documents and Settings", yet Vista does not my app to do that.

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this be helpful to you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx